# The SimpleThreads Example - Java tutorial

Tags: java

I tried searching on this question and couldn't able to find.

I was trying to understand the example provided in Java tutorial:
The SimpleThreads Example: 
    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

In, this example, when i comment out "//t.join(1000);" its showing the output as:

```
    main: Starting MessageLoop thread
    main: Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish
    main: Still waiting...
    main: Still waiting...
    ...
    ...
    main: Still waiting...
    Thread-5: A kid will eat ivy too
    main: Still waiting...
    main: Finally!
```

un-commenting "t.join(1000), its showing all the elements from importantInfo[] array.

In the above output, why its not showing all the elements from the array and its showing only the last one?

Comment: That's a pretty horrible example. It's probably best to add some breakpoints and use a debugger to decipher what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure it is printing all elements from the array - you just dont see it
As i tried not to print on the console but to write it in a file (140 KByte textfile oO), all 4 different strings are written ... maybe its some concurrency problem with the console, idk
maybe ure console output is limited? check your Eclipse / IDE settings

so the "still waiting" is printed several hundred or rather thousand times, and youre searching for 4 other strings - not that big suprise you cant find them in the mess

hope this helps a bit, although i agree - its a horrible example xD

Comment: I just routed the output to a text file, and its created the file of size 10.5 MB, but its showing the same output as I mentioned above.

Comment: strange ... how have you done it? you used the same IO-Stream for both threads? i used a printwriter `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("test.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("...");
writer.close();`